# Python Firebase Admin Sdk Query Timestamp

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

How can I retrieve documents that have a createdAt timestamp newer than a certain date?

Something like:

```
firstDayOfMonth = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
transactions = db.collection('productTransactions').where('createdAt', ">=", firstDayOfMonth).get()
```

Comment: Hi did you find a way to do this query in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `firstDayOfMonth` is of class `date`, while the Firebase uses format `Timestamp` for dates and time (which is `datetime` in Python).

You can do:

```py
firstDayOfMonth = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
# datetime.date(2019, 2, 1)

dt = datetime.datetime.combine(firstDayOfMonth, datetime.datetime.min.time())
# datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 1, 0, 0)

transactions = db.collection('productTransactions').where('createdAt', ">=", dt).get()
```